# Why is the git push syntax for creating a new remote branch from a detached HEAD so different?

Tags: git

Recently I had a scenario where I was in a detached HEAD state. I wanted to push this to a fork on github in order to share some work-in-progress code with a teammate. I had no need for a local branch name for this particular commit.

Clearly, this would not work:

```
git push sandy-github HEAD
```

That makes sense, as I wasn't specifying a name for the remote branch.

But I don't understand why this did not work:

```
git push sandy-github HEAD:mynewbranch
```

This resulted in the following error:

> error: unable to push to unqualified destination: mynewbranch
>   The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
>   begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:sandyarmstrong/myreponame.git'

I ended up having to do:

```
git push sandy-github HEAD:refs/heads/mynewbranch
```

This worked. From the docs:

> git push origin master:refs/heads/experimental
>
> Create the branch experimental in the origin repository by copying the current master branch. This form is only needed to create a new
>   branch or tag in the remote repository when the local name and the
>   remote name are different; otherwise, the ref name on its own will
>   work.

I just don't understand why this was necessary. I'm guessing there's something important about git I'm misunderstanding here. Why is this trickier syntax necessary just because the names don't match? Why isn't the `HEAD:mynewbranch` syntax sufficient to let git know that it should generate a new branch on the remote named "mynewbranch"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `refspec` part of the [`git push` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html#_options_a_id_options_a) has this (emphasis mine):

> The `<dst>` tells which ref on the remote side is updated with this push. ***Arbitrary expressions cannot be used here, an actual ref must be named.*** If `:<dst>` is omitted, the same ref as `<src>` will be updated.

In the normal state, git can determine that you meant to push to a certain branch (or tag) based on branch tracking and/or values of `push.default` in config.

In the detached HEAD state, git cannot guess whether you want to create a new branch or a new tag (both could be reasonable here).

It's possible to imply that the branch be created by creating the local branch first:

```
git checkout -b mynewbranch
git push -u sandy-github mynewbranch
```

If you don't want to checkout the branch you're pushing, you can use the `refs/heads/` prefix as you mentioned in your question:

```
git push sandy-github HEAD:refs/heads/mynewbranch
```

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, git does not apply the push.default matching rules while in the detached HEAD state? Because if I do as you suggest, and create a local branch named "mynewbranch", git is very happy to let me to `git push sandy-github HEAD:mynewbranch2` to create a new remote branch. It has no trouble then guessing that I want a branch and not a tag.

Comment: Yep, `push.default` only applies to named branches. In that example, you can even just do `git push origin HEAD`, and it will create a new branch with the correct name; it's just in the detached HEAD state that you need to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Git has a fair amount of "magic" or "DWIM"* in many commands.  "Push" has this: if you push local branch `b` to the remote and the remote has a `b`, it uses the magic/DWIM part to reconcile the local ref (whose "real" name is `refs/heads/b`) with the remote one (whose name, on the remote, is also `refs/heads/b`).  But you can also push `refs/tags/t`, or now that notes exist, `refs/notes/commits`.

It already also has magic/DWIM to realize that a local ref `y` that resolves to the local full-name `refs/x/y` should create the same `refs/x/y` on the remote when you use `y:y`, even if `y` does not exist on the remote.  It's just that if the local full-name does not resolve to something like this, that this fails.  It can even resolve HEAD when it is the symbolic name of a branch, but when HEAD is "detached", there is no symbolic name.

It *could* assume that `git push HEAD:foo` "means" to create `refs/heads/foo`.  That's probably the most likely, hence what you meant.  But, it does not (yet?).

*[DWIM: "Do What I Mean" (as opposed to what I say)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM).

Answer (score -1):

This actually works fine for me. Are you on an older version of git or something?

For reference, I ran the following:

```
MacBook:AndroidAsync[master*]$ git commit -a -m gitignore
[master 69851e1] gitignore
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
MacBook:AndroidAsync[master]$ git push origin HEAD:master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 343 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://git@github.com/koush/AndroidAsync
   04b2f79..69851e1  HEAD -> master
```

Version:

```
MacBook:AndroidAsync[master]$ git --version
git version 1.8.2.1 (Apple Git-45)
```

Also confirmed to work from detached HEAD:

```
MacBook:AndroidAsync[(no branch)]$ git push origin HEAD:master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 332 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 1 (delta 0)
To ssh://git@github.com/koush/AndroidAsync
   69851e1..ae2d1be  HEAD -> master
```

Comment: In both of your examples, you are pushing to master, which already exists on the remote branch. It should fail if you specify a new non-existent remote branch name.

Comment: To answer your question, I've tested on 1.8.4 on Windows and 1.8.2.3 on Mac.